# Why does the saved model starts with initital loss and accuracy values after loading in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am building a model for machine comprehension. It's a heavy model required to train on lots of data and this requires me more time. I have used keras callbacks to save model after every epoch and also save a history of loss and accuracy.

The problem is, when I am loading a trained model, and try to continue it's training using `initial_epoch` argument, the loss and accuracy values are same as untrained model.

Here is the code: https://github.com/ParikhKadam/bidaf-keras
The code used to save and load model is in /models/bidaf.py
The script I am using to load the model is:

```
from .models import BidirectionalAttentionFlow
from .scripts.data_generator import load_data_generators
import os
import numpy as np


def main():
    emdim = 400
    bidaf = BidirectionalAttentionFlow(emdim=emdim, num_highway_layers=2,
                                       num_decoders=1, encoder_dropout=0.4, decoder_dropout=0.6)
    bidaf.load_bidaf(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'saved_items', 'bidaf_29.h5')) 
    train_generator, validation_generator = load_data_generators(batch_size=16, emdim=emdim, shuffle=True)
    model = bidaf.train_model(train_generator, epochs=50, validation_generator=validation_generator, initial_epoch=29, 
                              save_history=False, save_model_per_epoch=False)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The training history is quite good which is:

```
epoch,accuracy,loss,val_accuracy,val_loss
0,0.5021367247352657,5.479433422293752,0.502228641179383,5.451400522458351
1,0.5028450897193741,5.234336488338403,0.5037527732234647,5.0748545675049
2,0.5036885394022954,5.042028017280698,0.5039489093881276,5.0298488218407975
3,0.503893446146289,4.996997425685413,0.5040753162241299,4.976164487656699
4,0.5040576918224873,4.955544574118662,0.5041905890181151,4.931354981493792
5,0.5042372655790888,4.909940965651957,0.5043896965802341,4.881359395178988
6,0.504458428129642,4.8542871887472465,0.5045972716586732,4.815464454729135
7,0.50471843351102,4.791098495962496,0.5048680457262408,4.747811231472629
8,0.5050776754196002,4.713560494026321,0.5054184527602898,4.64730478015052
9,0.5058853749443502,4.580552254050073,0.5071290369370443,4.446513280167718
10,0.5081544614246304,4.341471499420364,0.5132941329030303,4.145318906086552
11,0.5123970410575613,4.081624463197288,0.5178775145611896,4.027316586998608
12,0.5149879128865782,3.9577423109634613,0.5187159608315838,3.950151870168726
13,0.5161411008840144,3.8964761709052578,0.5191430166876064,3.906301355196609
14,0.5168211272672539,3.8585826589385697,0.5191263493850466,3.865382308412537
15,0.5173216891201444,3.830764191839807,0.519219763635108,3.8341492204942607
16,0.5177805591697787,3.805340048675155,0.5197178382215892,3.8204319018292585
17,0.5181171635676399,3.7877712072310343,0.5193657963810704,3.798006804522368
18,0.5184295824699279,3.77086071548255,0.5193122694008523,3.7820449101377243
19,0.5187343664397653,3.7555085003534194,0.5203585262348183,3.776260506494833
20,0.519005008308583,3.7430062334375065,0.5195983755362352,3.7605361109533995
21,0.5192872482429703,3.731001830462149,0.5202017035842986,3.7515058917231405
22,0.5195097722222706,3.7194103983513553,0.5207148585133065,3.7446572377159795
23,0.5197511249107636,3.7101052441559905,0.5207420740297026,3.740088335181619
24,0.5199862479678652,3.701593302911729,0.5200187951731082,3.7254406861185188
25,0.5200847805044403,3.6944093077914464,0.520112738649039,3.7203616696860786
26,0.5203289568582412,3.6844954882274092,0.5217114634669081,3.7214983577364547
27,0.5205629846610852,3.6781935968943595,0.520915311442328,3.705435317731209
28,0.5206827641463226,3.6718110897539193,0.5214088439286978,3.7003081666703377
```

Also, I have already taken care of loading custom objects such as layers, loss function and accuracy.

I am kind of frustrated by now as I took me days to train this model upto epochs and now I can't resume training. I have referred various threads in keras issues and found many people are facing such issues but can't find a solution.

Someone in a thread said that "Keras will not save RNN states" (I ain't using stateful RNNs) and someone else said "Keras reinitializes all the weights before saving which we can handle using a flag." I mean, if such problems exist in Keras, what will be the use of functions like save().

I have also tried saving only weights after every epoch and then building model from scratch and then loading those weights into it. But that didn't work. You can find the old code I used to save weights only in the above listed github repo's older branches.

I have referred this issue with no help - #4875

That issue is open from past two years. Can't understand what all the developers are doing! Is anyone here who can help? Should I switch to tensorflow or I will face the same issues in that too?

Please help...

**Edit1:**
I haven't tried saving model using model.save() but I have seen people on other threads saying that the issue was solved with model.save() and models.save_model(). If it is actually solved, ModelCheckpoint should also save optimizer state to resume training but it doesn't (or can't) whatsoever the reason. I have verified the code of ModelCheckpoint callback which indirectly calls model.save() which leads a call to models.save_model(). So theoretically, if the issue in the base i.e. models.save_model() is solved, then it should also be solved in other functions.

Sorry, but I don't have a powerful machine to check this practically. If someone here has, I have shared my code on github and the link is provided in the issue. Please try the resume training on it and detect the cause of this problem.

I am using the computer provided by a national institute and hence, students here need to share this single computer for their projects. I can't use that computer for such tasks. Thank you..

**Edit2:**
Recently, I tried to check if the weights are saved correctly. For that, I evaluated the model with my validation generator. I saw that the output loss and accuracy remained the same as those in the beginning of model training. Seeing this, I reached a conclusion that its actually the issue with saving weights of the model. I might be wrong here..

BTW, I have also used `multi_gpu_model()` in my model code. Can it cause this issue? I can't try training model on CPU as it too heavy for that and will take a few days for only 1 epoch to complete. Can anyone help debugging?

I see no response in such issues these days. Just list current issues on the README.md in keras github so that users can be aware before trying keras out and wasting months behind it.